Low disk space warning on "Filesystem root"
I have a Ubuntu machine in VMWare.
Initially, it had 40Gb storage but recently I start getting low disk space warnings so I decided to increase it to 60 with GParted.
The problem is, I still get the warning on boot.
The thing is, I am not sure what am I looking at. The alert says there are only 600Mb available, Disk Usage Analyzer says root is at 100% out of 25Gb while reporting the total filesystem capacity at 42Gb and in Disks I see the partition at 60Gb after I increase it from 40Gb.
Any ideas? Am I reading this wrong?


You resized the partition but not the underlying virtual volume (LVM) nor the filesystem on the partition.
Your filesystem is an LVM volume that is ext4 formatted.
Open the Command Prompt and run sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv && sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv to expand the LVM and the filesystem to fill the available space.  You won't get those warnings anymore.
If that set of commands don't work, then try sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv && sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv.

Start Button > Utilities > Disks
The link below has a different language, but it has the full information.

enter link description here
