partition->check greyed out in gparted
Recently resized my system partition with gparted on Ubuntu 24.04
It is a LUKS encrypted partition
The system works fine but Ubuntu somehow cannot access the extra space on the resized partition
This extra space appears grey in gparted and when I query free space in Nemo I get 7 GB instead of 185.97 GB (178.97+7)
gparted says to click on Partition->Check in the menu to resolve this
However, the Check option is greyed out
It is also greyed out if I boot on a USB stick and access this disk via gparted then
How to ungrey the Check option in gparted?

The solution is to use lvresize or resize2fs to resize the filesystem such that it takes up the entire partition.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2487570 &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1521547/low-disk-space-warning-on-filesystem-root

Can I resize a LUKS partition?
Yes, you can, as LUKS doesn't store the partition size. Whether you should is a different question. Better would be to backup, recreation of the encrypted partition with new size, recreation of the filesystem and restore. This gets around the tricky business of resizing the filesystem. Resizing a LUKS container does not resize the filesystem in it. The backup is really non-optional here, as a lot can go wrong, resulting in partial or complete data loss. Using something like gparted to resize an encrypted partition is slow, but typically works. This will not change the size of the filesystem hidden under the encryption though.
https://www.golinuxcloud.com/resize-luks-partition-shrink-extend-decrypt/

Thank you David
