Ubuntu new setup dos not take all disk size
I have setup a new ubuntu 24 with a 75G of disk. When I log, I see that my disk is only 35Gig and not 75. I triggered DISKS, I discovered that

So as I am not a ubuntu expert, how can extend the main file system with rest of Gigs? Is there a way to extend it safely?

You created LVM - logical Volumes. That typically does not fully allocate the LVM in case you want separate volumes for another / or /home or anything else. If you want encryption you have to use LVM, otherwise not suggested for new users, but often used for servers. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1521547/low-disk-space-warning-on-filesystem-root & https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/733982/expanding-a-drive-partition-without-data-loss & https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

Thanks, yes this did the job

What you've done is use LVM in your setup, and by default that annoyingly only uses a portion of your drive.
You can easily expand that to fill the LVM partition by doing the following:
sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv

Then you'll be set.
